# setting a level in the ROC function

Tags: r, prediction, proc-r-package

I am trying to obtain sens, spec, npv and ppv for the ability of two patient scoring systems and their ability to predict admission. To explain the data:

'Etriage' is electronic triage system (scores from 1-5),
AETriage is a face-to-face triage system (socres 1-5).
Admitted has 2 levels as factors 0 - not admitted, 1 - admitted.

eg:

```
df <- data.frame(
    Etriage=c(2,3,3,5,2,5,3,3,4,3),
    AETriage=c(3,4,4,3,2,4,4,3,4,1), 
    Admitted=c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1))
```

I want to compare the two scores ability to predict admission and have been trying to use pROC to do this (taken from the overall dataset):

```
library(pROC)
auc(df$Admitted, df$AETriage)

ci.auc(df$Admitted, df$AETriage)
ROC_AETriage_Admitted<-roc(df$Admitted,df$AETriage)
print(ROC_AETriage_Admitted)

OperatingValuesAETriage <- coords(ROC_AETriage_Admitted, "all", 
    ret=c("sensitivity","specificity","npv","ppv","threshold"), transpose = FALSE)

print(OperatingValuesAETriage)
```

How would I code 2 operating levels (LOW acuity = score 3-5 and HIGH acuity = 1-2) and assess their ability to predict admission?

Thanks!

Comment: If I am understanding correctly, couldn't you simply code a new variable for this: 
`df$e_triag_cat <- ifelse(df$Etriage %in% c(1:2), 1, ifelse(df$Etriage %in% c(3:5), 0, NA))` then `pROC::auc(df$Admitted, df$e_triag_cat)` - apologies if I misunderstood the question

Comment: thank you for your comment. this gives dichotomization to two levels and can't run ROC on that. I want to set an operating value of 1-2 cut off and 3-5 cut off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use a textual score (or factors), because in order to build a ROC curve we need to *rank* the data, which cannot be done automatically on simple text (is "High" higher than "Low"? A computer wouldn't know that).

However, R has a textual data type for that: [ordered factors](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/factor.html), which are supported (to some extent) by pROC:

```
df$Etriage_binary <- ordered(
    ifelse(df$Etriage <= 2, "High", "Low"),
    levels = c("Low", "High"))

pROC::auc(df$Admitted, df$Etriage_binary)
```

Although thresholds aren't reported accurately, it works, but [this dichotomization is lossy and there are many reasons why you don't actually want to do it](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/372236/what-is-the-formula-to-calculate-the-area-under-the-roc-curve-from-a-contingency/372977#372977).

Comment: thank you that is very helpful calimo. Could you help answer a similar question. Why does the following code returns 6 levels with the coords function rather than the 5 I would expect (as there each system triages at 1-5).

```auc(df$Admitted, df$AETriage)
ci.auc(df$Admitted, df$AETriage)
ROC_AETriage_Admitted<-roc(df$Admitted,df$AETriage)
print(ROC_AETriage_Admitted)
OperatingValuesAETriage <- coords(ROC_AETriage_Admitted, "all", ret=c("sensitivity","specificity","npv","ppv","threshold"), transpose = FALSE)
print(OperatingValuesAETriage)```

Comment: @docalexh this sounds like a different question, please post this as a new one.